# Xcode, where to assign the segue identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Pardon me for beginner's question.
I know I can switch to another screen (ViewController) like this

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier ("SecondViewController", sender: self)
```

but I can't seem to find where to assign my 2nd screen the id, I just find Storyboard ID, is that it?

I've already tried, only received a crash with the following error:

> Receiver () has no segue
>   with identifier 'SecondViewController'

Any idea? thanks

Comment: If you are a Swift beginner, you really should learn Swift 3, not Swift 2, and use Xcode 8, not Xcode 7. Only use the older tools if you have been given a specific job to do with those specific tools.

Comment: Hi, because the tutorial I bought a while ago was using Swift 2, I'm following it

Comment: You need a modern tutorial. You are wasting your time learning an outdated form of the language. A lot has changed in Swift 3. Start with Apple's free book - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html

Comment: It probably is better to learn Swift 3 if you're starting from scratch but the segue handlers haven't changed drastically between v 7 and v 8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*Segue Identifier* is *not* the same as *storyboard ID*, storyboard ID used when you want to create a View Controller based on that specific storyboard -and it has to be unique, unlike the segue identifier-.

*If you already know how to create a segue, you can skip this part.*

### **Adding a segue between two viewControllers:**

From the Interface Builder, press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and drag between the two View Controllers that you want to link (make sure that you are dragging from the view controller itself, not the its main view). You should see:

[image]

Choose the "Show" -for instance-, the output should look like this:

[image]

As shown above, the arrow that surrounded by the red rectangle is the segue.

*Additional note:* if you selected the "Show" option, you have to embed your first view Controller in a Navigation Controller (select your first viewController -> Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller), the output should looks like:

[image]

Because the "Show" means pushing into a navigation controller stack.

### **Assigning an identifier for the segue:**

Select the segue, from the attribute inspector you'll see "Identifier" text field, that's it! make sure to insert the exact same name that used in `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

*If you don't know where to find the attribute inspector, it is on the top right looks like:*

[image]

---

### **Furthermore:**

For adding *multiple* segues from one View Controller, follow the same process (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + drag from the first controller to each other View Controller), the output should looks like:

[image]

In this case, you might face the issue how to recognize which segue has been performed, overriding [`prepare(for:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare) method is the solution, you can make the checking based on the segue `identifier` property:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "firstSegueIdentifier") {
        // ...
    } else if (segue.identifier == "secondSegueIdentifier") {
        //...
    }
}
```

which would be the name that you have added to the segue in the storyboard.

Comment: For me, ctrl+clicking from one viewcontroller to another just moves the first viewcontroller to cover the second on the storyboard.

Comment: @chodobaggins first, select the viewcontroller itself and ctrl + drag from the yellow circle that appears on top of it to the desired controller.

Answer (score 4):

In your code

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier ("SecondViewController", sender: self)
```

the string "SecondViewController" is looking like storyboard id . At the same place you have to write the segue identifier , not storyboard id .

Follow the Screenshot and assign segue identifier name by clicking on the segue on right top bar field. you can do like this

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier ("WriteSegueIdentifierName", sender: self)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answers provided, here's what it would look like in Xcode 12:

1. Select the segue link in Main Storyboard view

[image: Segue Link]

2. Navigate to the Attribute Inspector and add an Identifier (if one does not exist)

[image: Xcode 12 Attribute Inspector]

3. Add the Identifier to your code. Done!

[image: Add to code]

Answer (score 0):

When you link a View controller to another View controller in the storyboard, in the link between them you need to assign a segue identifier i.e "SecondViewController" only then your code will work.

Alternatively, you can also show another view controller through storyboard id using self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("//storyboard id of that view controller") and then either use present/show view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate viewController like this:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login")
self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Show Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDvSh.png)

[image]

Click on Present Modally segue label... and on the Attributes Inspector input Identifier