# Present a viewcontroller from a custom modal popover

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, viewcontroller, popover

I was able to create a custom popover and added some button, but when I tried to connect it with a segue, it doesn't appear. 
Is there any solution for this?

I tried using this code:

```
@IBAction func WishlistView(sender: AnyObject) {
     self.presentViewController(WishlistViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Hopefully, someone will answer this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifier", sender: self)`, if your don't know how to assign identifier for a segue, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904328/xcode-7-where-to-assign-the-segue-identifier.).

So your code should be like:

Swift 2:

```
@IBAction func WishlistView(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

Swift 3:

```
@IBAction func WishlistView(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: When i tried to add connection/segue the controller became small same size with the popover, i used push, when i use the modal segue navigation bar disappears, I use the popover to serve as "picker of action"