# performSegue on animation finished, what identifier?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I want to perform a segue from my loading viewController to the next viewController when an animation is finished:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.loggo_image.alpha = 1.0

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LogInView", sender: nil)
        }, completion: nil)

}
```

I know the code itself probably is wrong, but it's just there displaying the example. Since I don't have any buttons or similar to create a segue to the next view in the storyboard (CTRL click in storyboard), I guess I need to do it programmatically. Though I can't work out how to set the "identifier" of the view I want to go to. As shown in the example, I tried simply using the custom class name, which isn't right.

So how? Is it Storyboard ID? Title?

Comment: refer https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through your issue:

> I want to perform a segue from my loading viewController to the next
>   viewController when an animation is finished

When an animation finished means that the code is wrong (you are right for saying *"I know the code itself probably is wrong"*), you should perform your the segue in the `completion` block, as follows:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
            self.loggo_image.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: { _ in
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LogInView", sender: nil)
        })
```

> Though I can't work out how to set the "identifier" of the view I want
>   to go to. As shown in the example, I tried simply using the custom
>   class name, which isn't right.
>
> So how? Is it Storyboard ID? Title?

I fully described how to exactly achieve this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904328/xcode-where-to-assign-the-segue-identifier/39905378#39905378).

**ALSO:**

If you had a case that you should navigate to another viewController without using segues, you check this (In this case you have to use *Storyboard ID*):

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

// "nextView" is Storyboard ID
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextView") as NextViewController

// now you can choose between pushing:
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewContro‌​ller, animated: true)
// or presenting:
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can Ctr-Drag from the ViewController itself (the yellow circle on the screenshot) to the viewcontroller you want to segue to.

[image]

It will create a segue and you can set its identifier there and then call `performSegue` as you did, using the identifier you set in the storyboard.

[image]