# Segueing from TableView with many sections

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uitableview

I have the following settings tableView:

[image]

I want to perform a segue from each of the cells (as indicated by the disclosures) to another view controller. The problem is I don't want to make six different view controllers, especially since many of them will be almost identical, containing one or two text fields and a label. Is there any way I can just make one view controller and change it upon which cell is clicked?

Comment: What is stopping you from creating one view controller and configuring that destination view controller in `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: In your `prepareForSegue` method, call `tableVIew.indexPathForSelectedRow` to know what cell was tapped on. Then configure your destination view controller accordingly

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is I don't want to make six different view controllers,
>   especially since many of them will be almost identical, containing one
>   or two text fields and a label.

That's definitely true. You can achieve this by adding *only one segue* -without the need of adding six different segues- from the settings ViewController to the next one (details ViewController); Based on which row -in which section- has been selected, you can perform to your segue and sending the desired data.

**1- Adding Segue:**

you need to add a segue from the settings ViewController to the details ViewController. **Make sure** that the segue has been connected from the settings ViewController itself, but *not* from any of table view cell. After adding the segue on the storyboard, you need to add an identifier for it, I'll call it -in my code snippet example- "toDetails".

*If you don't know how to add an identifier for the segue, you might want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904328/xcode-where-to-assign-the-segue-identifier/39905378#39905378).*

**2- Sending Desired Data:**

For the purpose of simplifying, I assumed that the data you want to send is just a single string variable, called -in my code snippet example- `dataToSend`.

It goes as follows:

**Settings ViewController:**

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

//...
private var dataToSend = ""
//...

//...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: self)
}
//...

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // tableView should be connected as an IBOutlet
    guard let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
        print("Something went wrong when selected a row!")
        return
    }

    if selectedIndexPath.section == 0 { // Account Section

        if selectedIndexPath.row == 0 { // Name Row
            dataToSend = "name"
        } else if selectedIndexPath.row == 1 { // School Row
            dataToSend = "school"
        } else if selectedIndexPath.row == 2 { // Grade Row
            dataToSend = "grade"
        }

    } else if selectedIndexPath.section == 1 { // Private Section

        if selectedIndexPath.row == 0 { // Email Row
            dataToSend = "email"
        } else if selectedIndexPath.row == 1 { // Password Row
            dataToSend = "password"
        } else if selectedIndexPath.row == 2 { // Phone Number Row
            dataToSend = "phone"
        }

    }

    let detailsViewController = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
    detailsViewController.receivedData = dataToSend
    }

    //...
}
```

**Take it Further:**

It is a good practice when working with such a case to use *enums* instead of checking rows numbers, that leads to more readable code:

```
enum Sections:Int {
    case
    account = 0,
    privacy = 1
}

enum AccountRows:Int {
    case
    name = 0,
    school = 1,
    grade = 2
}

enum PrivacyRows:Int {
    case
    email = 0,
    password = 1,
    phone = 2
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    //...
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        // tableView should be connected as an IBOutlet
        guard let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
            print("Something went wrong when selected a row!")
            return
        }

        // tuple of (section, row)
        switch (selectedIndexPath.section, selectedIndexPath.row) {
            // Accounts Section
            case (Sections.account.rawValue, AccountRows.name.rawValue):
                dataToSend = "name"
            case (Sections.account.rawValue, AccountRows.school.rawValue):
                dataToSend = "school"
            case (Sections.account.rawValue, AccountRows.grade.rawValue):
                dataToSend = "grade"

            // Privacy Section
            case (Sections.privacy.rawValue, PrivacyRows.email.rawValue):
                dataToSend = "email"
            case (Sections.privacy.rawValue, PrivacyRows.password.rawValue):
                dataToSend = "password"
            case (Sections.privacy.rawValue, PrivacyRows.phone.rawValue):
                dataToSend = "phone"
            default:
                print("Something went wrong when checking Section and Rows!")
        }

        let detailsViewController = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
        detailsViewController.receivedData = dataToSend
    }
    //...
}
```

Cheers up! Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a new View Controller i am naming it as "VController"

Create enum in "VController" above the view didload :

  public enum VCType:Int {
        case  name = 1
        case school = 2
        case grade = 3
    }
    var selectedVc:VCType!

In viewdidload of "VController":

 if selectedVc == .name {
            // do whatever you want
        }
        else if selectedVc == .school {
            // do whatever you want
        }
        else if
        ..........
        ..........


Code For First ViewController :

above the view didload :

 var selectedType:VController.VCType!


    // in didSelectRowAtIndexPath
     selectedType = .school // if selecting school
     perform segue


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "mySegue"{
                let nextScene = segue.destination as? VController
                nextScene?.selectedVc = selectedType
            }
        }
```