# Perform a segue programmatically

Tags: swift, transition, uicollectionviewcell

Hi I'm trying to perform a segue programmatically without the Storyboard. Currently I have this as my code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popOutNoteExpanded" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! ExpandedCellViewController
        let cell = sender as! AnnotatedPhotoCell
        sourceCell = cell
        vc.picture = cell.imageView.image
        print("button pressed")
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "popOutNoteExpanded", sender: indexPath)
}
```

When I click on the collection view cell it's saying that:

> has no segue with identifier 'popOutNoteExpanded'.

Not sure how to perform my custom animated transition.

Comment: You may find your solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39905378/3687801)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Segues are components of storyboard. If you don't have a storyboard, you can't perform segues. But you can use present view controller like this:

```
let vc = ViewController() //your view controller
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I need to confirm that I can't use a segue identifier without storyboard. I know how to present view. Just need to fiddle with my code a bit.

Answer (score 35):

To trigger a segue programmatically, you have to follow steps:
1. Set it up in Storyboard by **dragging your desired segue between two view controllers** and **set its identifier** (for example, in your case is "popOutNoteExpanded") in Attributes Inspector section.
2. Call it programmatically

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "popOutNoteExpanded", sender: cell)
```

Please check if you set its identifier correctly or not.

Besides, in your above code, you put **an incorrect sender**.
In your *prepare()* method, you use the sender as a *UITableViewCell*, but you call *performSegue()* with sender as a *IndexPath*.
You need a cell by calling:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

And then you can perform a segue:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "popOutNoteExpanded", sender: cell)
```

Comment: No it really shouldn't the question is about performing segue WITHOUT a storyboard

Answer (score 3):

Additional to the correct answer, please be aware that if you are in a navigation stack (say, you are in a Settings page and want to segue to an MyAccountVC) you should use:

```
let vc = MyAccountVC()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

If the navigated VC appears with a transparent background during the transition, just set the `backgoundColor` of it to `.white`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was presenting a TableViewController, without a segue defined, and found it was necessary to instantiate from the storyboard otherwise `tableViewCells` couldn't be dequeued in `cellForRowAt`.

```
let vc = (storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourTableViewController") as? YourTableViewController)!
self.navigationController!.pushViewController( vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: It would be useful/interesting to understand what warranted this down vote?

Comment: programmitically to me means no storyboard use. so the views are created, and iboutlets are all in the code. how do I add segue to controller without storyboard