# Swift - Open new View after click on Button

Tags: ios, swift, button, view

I would like to open new View after clicking on a button. It works, when I make it by UIButton in Main.storyboard, however, I need to make it in code, because I have to use some if-statements with login/password. I tried to make it like it was suggested in other similar questions, but it doesn't work:

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: UIButton) {

   performSegue(withIdentifier: "Second", sender: self)}
```

Id of login-view: **First**;

Id of the second view: **Second**

[image]

Comment: You don't use the Id of the view, you use the Id of the **seuge**

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904328/xcode-where-to-assign-the-segue-identifier/39905378#39905378

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Segue doesn't look to have an identifier in the screenshot. Can you confirm. Please add an identifier to your segue from first view to second and then alter the below code with the name of segue identifier

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segueidentifier", sender: self)}
```

To add identifier on the segue, click on the segue in your storyboard and then on the right hand side in the Attributes Inspector add identifier in the Storyboard Segue section

[image: Identifier]

Comment: Pleasure. Could you accept the answer in that case :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use storyboard Id

```
 let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondStoryboardId") as! SecondViewController
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use **storyboard ID** for segues. There will be **segue identifier** separately. When you drag&drop segue you will get one line connected between the screens. Click on that to add segue identifier. You need to provide that **segue ID** here

You can see segue connection from the below image:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set Segue identifier as below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Select the segue** and give a Identifier/Name ( Here , I've put `toSecond`) at **Attribute Inspector** 
and then perform segue .

ScreenShot : 
[image]

Source Code :

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: UIButton) {

   performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSecond", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Also make sure that your segue is from the initial VC not the button...

Comment: It is more like a comment than an answer

Comment: Good looks, next time I ll add a video ♥️

Comment: Just let me know when you will put it on video :D

Comment: Bet say less 

Comment: Dont forget mentioning me hah