# Segue not Identified

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I want to switch between `viewController` by using `containerViewController`.
For this I created multiple segues and `viewController`.

when I run

```
func segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent(_ identifier: String){
       self.segueIdentifier = identifier
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.segueIdentifier, sender: nil)
}
```

in it's parent controller file it works fine but when I called it through other controller file it gives error

> ContainerViewController: 0x7fd703707b40>) has no segue with identifier 'second''

This is how i called it in other `viewController`

```
let vc = ParentViewController()
vc.segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent("second")
```

Here "second" is the Identifier given to segue in `storyBoard`

Above code is written in AddTarget of button.
So when I tap button I get Error

Comment: You need to set identifier into storyboard please check this link. its may help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904328/xcode-where-to-assign-the-segue-identifier/39905378#39905378

Comment: Thank you for your response. but method is working fine when I called it in viewDidLoad of parent view controller

Comment: I'm not sure I'd use segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent - just create a segue from the parentview to where you want to traverse. If you want to call a segue in the child view, just call a function in the child view to segue. Job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in same a storyBoard then you can simply do this -
Take a button in your `firstVC` and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + drag a segue upto your `secondVC`. Then click on the segue. (the round thing on between two view controller). -

[image]

And set a identifier for that (here `about` is the identifier, you can give any name for this)-

[image]

Here is the code -

```
@IBAction func UserDetailVC(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifierName", sender: sender)
    }
```

Comment: thank you
but code is not woking only when i called it through third file.
it's working fine with parent file

Comment: @ShivamTrivedi set another identifier for your third viewController.

Comment: I have 5 viewControllers and I set Different identifiers for each

Comment: Do the same thing for each viewControllers of yours.  Let me know if there any complications.

Comment: If there is any with identifier then why it is working fine with its own file.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts,
But my code is not working only if I called it through other view.
otherwise it working fine