# what is Item in ContainerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uicontainerview

i'm new in swift and first time using Container `ViewController` to handle multiple controllers.

**storyBoard Image**

[image]

**Item Image**

[image]

But I don't know what is Item here. 
I can use segue in `containerView` Class but not able to use segue in main `viewController`.
as i'm not aware about "item" as shown in Image

why is there "item", "item1" and "item2" and why 2 segue's has same name as "item"
please help me and share information about it.

Comment: Item, Item 1 and Item 2 are just names for your scenes. Also, two scenes are named Item, that's why you see two segues pointing to a scene named Item.

Comment: Thanks, will you please read this question  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247393/segue-not-identified)