# I need to take data from my firebase database and put it into labels, but the data needs to correspond to my tableView cell title

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building out a fairly simple app and have run into a problem. Right now My app has a home screen and a table view with the name of an Event in each cell. The data is loading fine from my database to my cell and when you click on the cell it takes you to a new View Controller. I want to put specific info into each label that corresponds to the name of my event. For example if the cell reads STEM Leadership Confrence when I click on it I want the three labels to have text that matches: the date, point value and time frame. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. (Swift 4 and Firebase RT database)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


var refa: DatabaseReference!

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var posts = [eventStruct]()

    @IBOutlet weak var Tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refa = Database.database().reference()
        loadNews()
        Tableview?.delegate = self
        Tableview?.dataSource = self

    }
    struct eventStruct {
        let Name: String!
        let date: String!
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TableToSignUp", sender: self)


    }

    func loadNews() {
        refa.child("Events").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]
            {
                let Name = valueDictionary["Name"]
                let date = valueDictionary["date"]
                self.posts.insert(eventStruct(Name: Name, date: date), at: 0)
                self.Tableview.reloadData()


            }
        })
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = Tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AllEventsCell", for: indexPath)

        //let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
        cell.textLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row].Name
        //let cell2 = Tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AllEventsCell", for: indexPath)



        return cell
}

}
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var Nav: UINavigationBar!
@IBOutlet weak var NumOfParticipants: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var TimeFrame: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var EndDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Points: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Create: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ViewAll: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var CreateEventButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ViewMyEventsButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Name: UITextField!
var ref: DatabaseReference?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    CreateEventButton?.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    CreateEventButton?.clipsToBounds = true
    Create?.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    Create?.clipsToBounds = true


    ViewMyEventsButton?.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    ViewMyEventsButton?.clipsToBounds = true


    ViewAll?.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    ViewAll?.clipsToBounds = true

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func CreateEvent(_ sender: Any) {
    let text: String = (Name.text)!
    let date: String = (EndDate.text)!
    let point: String = (Points.text)!
    let timeFrame: String = (TimeFrame.text)!
    let numOfpar: String = (NumOfParticipants.text)!
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    let now = Date()

    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current

    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"


    let dateString = formatter.string(from: now)

    let newUserData = ["Name": text, "date": date, "Point Value": point, "Time Frame": timeFrame, "Volunteers Needed": numOfpar, "Date Created": dateString] as [String: Any]



    ref?.child("Events").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(newUserData)




}


     //,; ["Amount of Points": point];["Date End": date]



}
```

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate{

```
let userDefault  = UserDefaults()

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    if let error = error{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return


    }else{
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email
        let str = email
        let me = str?.count
        let int = (me!-9)
        let secondInt =  (me!-8)
        let XStr = str?.dropFirst(secondInt)
        let NewStr = str?.dropFirst(int)




        guard let authentication = user.authentication else{return}
        let crendential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: crendential) {(result, error)in
            if error == nil {
                self.userDefault.set(true, forKey: "usersignedIn")
                self.userDefault.synchronize()


                 if(NewStr == "gmail.com"){

                    self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TeacherSegue", sender: self)
                }

                else if(XStr == "aisd.net"){
                    self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TeacherSegue", sender: self)


                }
            }else {
                //self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Wegue", sender: self)

                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "me")
            }
        }




    }


}
var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    return true
}


@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication:options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: [:])
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                             annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}


func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

}

```
Events-
      -LdK2x1kNMB6fBw0Oorn
      -LdLPGh-_SXIjM7DhjDV
      -LdPVnBYQtAtSOyZM1IR- 
          Date: "2019-04-28"
          Name:"STEM Leadership Confrence"
          Point Value: "12"
          Time Frame: "3-4"
```

Comment: Do you want to change the text when the user touch on your cell? And could you add the code of your cell?

Comment: I don't want to change the text of my cell if that's what you're asking just the labels in the View Controller. I've added the code for all my files, the code for the cell is in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the information to the next `UIViewController`.

First, put all the information that you need inside your `eventStruct` and update your struct initialization inside the Firebase callback.

```
struct EventStruct {
   ...
   var timeFrame: String!
   var points: Int!
}
```

If you are using storyboards, you need to implement the `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` method and use `segue` to perform the transition to the next view. This link will help you to add an identifier to your `segue` [Xcode, where to assign the segue identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904328/xcode-where-to-assign-the-segue-identifier)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let detailToSend: EventStruct = posts[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetailSegue", sender: detailToSend)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ViewController, let detailToSend = sender as? EventStruct {            
        vc.detail = detailToSend
    }
}
```

If you are using view code, you just need the `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let detailToSend: EventStruct = posts[indexPath.row]
    let vc = ViewController()
    vc.detail = detailToSend
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

After that, in `viewDidLoad()` of your `ViewController` assign the information to the labels.

```
TimeFrame.text = detail.timeFrame
```

Another advice, take a look at swift best practices, like https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide or use SwiftLint in your project.

Comment: I implemented your changes and I get the error                                                           
 " Use of unresolved identifier 'detail' "  in my view did load method and the error "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'detail'; did you mean 'retain'?" in the prepare method.

Comment: I used segues by the way

Comment: you need to create a new var in your `ViewController`, for example: `var detail: EventStruct?`

Comment: check if the value is reaching the `ViewController` in var detail: EventStruct? { didSet { print(detail) } } or put a breakpoint in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) `, before and inside the if. You can check in the viewDidLoad as well, with a print(detail).