# How to transfer the data from a right button on Navigation Bar to another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I have a Navigation Bar with two buttons: Back and Add. I need to transfer data (UIImage) to second View Controller (ViewControllerFilters2), when I click on the add button. I have the "prepare for segue" function but it doesn't work. When I click on "Add", I go to the second controller, but imageView doesn't have an image.

I also have another button "Apply" on view controller, and for this button this function works but not for button on navigation bar.

I tried to change my code, but I don't have a lot of knowledge to do it. And don't know, where is the problem.

I want my Add button do the same function as Apply button, i.e. I want delete Apply button  and change it to Add button

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "✔", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
}

@objc func addTapped() {

    let filterTwoController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "filter2") as! ViewControllerFilters2
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(filterTwoController, animated: true)

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let nextController = segue.destination as? ViewControllerFilters2
        nextController?.filteredImage = imageView.image!

}
```

Comment: You need to use `performSegue` (if there is any), not push if you want to use that `prepare` method.

Answer (score 3):

```
@objc func addTapped() {

let filterTwoController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "filter2") as! ViewControllerFilters2
filterTwoController.filteredImage = imageView.image!
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(filterTwoController, animated: true)
}
```

that should fix your issue, because the navigationController?.pushViewController has ***nothing*** to do with the segue

Comment: I change it, but I have the same problem. It doesn't work, because image view on the filter2 controller doesn't have an image. It is nil.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve the issue, you should do the following:

- Make sure that there is a segue created (from the navigation item to the next view controller) on your storyboard. If you don't know how to do it, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904328/xcode-where-to-assign-the-segue-identifier/39905378#39905378). You could add the bar button from the storyboard thus create the segue.
- Currently, you are calling `navigationController?.pushViewController`, which is *not* related to the segue, what you should do instead is to call:

  `self.performSegueWithIdentifier ("SecondViewController", sender: self)`

Comment: I add button on navigation bar without storyboard. I can't do a segue in storyboard, because there I don't have a button "Add" on my ViewController. So, I do it with code in my addTapped method. And I have a segue between two controllers, when I launch my app. But I don't have image in imageView in the second controller. It is nil

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
@objc func addTapped() {

let filterTwoController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "filter2") as! ViewControllerFilters2
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(filterTwoController, animated: true)
}
```

to this:

```
@objc func addTapped() {

let filterTwoController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "filter2") as! ViewControllerFilters2
filterTwoController.filteredImage = imageView.image!
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(filterTwoController, animated: true)
}
```

As Ahmad F said, you are calling navigationController?.pushViewController, which is not related to the segue, so you need to set the image before you push the view controller.

Comment: I change it, but I have the same problem. It doesn't work, because image view on the filter2 controller doesn't have an image. It is nil.